# ImageMagick: how to provide Image generation directory path?

Tags: php, zend-framework, imagick

I am using ImageMagick [Caption Best Fit](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#caption_bestfit) in my code to generate a best fit text image.

PHP Code:

```
$tempPath = realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/temp');
$command = 'convert -background none -fill black -pointsize '.$captionFontSize.' -size '.$resizeBoxWidth.'x'.$resizeBoxHeight.' caption:"'.$myCaption.'" '.$tempPath.'/'.$randName.'.png';
$ex = exec($command);
```

It all works fine in my localhost running xampp on windows. It creates the image in the public/temp directory perfectly. The same code is not working fine on my hosting server running linux. The problem is the command is not executing due to which the image is not generated.

I google, if my way of specifying the path is correct but i am not getting any correct answers.

What do you think is the problem ?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please give some information on the server? Is it a virtual server / managed server, what is the OS, is imagemagick installed, ...?

Comment: @StefanNeubert - I am not aware of the details of the server. I will update my question once i know. But the imagemagick is definetly installed. When i do phpinfo() it shows all the information of the imagick library, which means that its installed. Thank you.

Comment: Add these settings and run the script again, 

error_reporting(-1); // to enable all errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

Comment: Also double check exec is an allowed function, there is an ini setting to turn it(along with any other functions you don't want people running) off. `disable_functions=exec`

Comment: Thank you for all your valuable reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temp folder had no appropriate permission on the server. So when i did,

```
chmod 777 temp
```

It solved the problem.
Lesson learnt - To thoroughly check the file/folder permissions.